# HTML CGI Script with MySQL

Tags: python, html, mysql, cgi

I'm just trying to write simple code to insert data from form to SQL DB using Python via CGI.  I got CGI portion working and it works fine but soon as I add import statement for mysql it breaks it and I get Internal Server Error code.  Here is what I got:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#!/usr/bin/mysql

import cgi, cgitb
import mysql

print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("<html>")

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print("Hello %s %s" % (first_name, last_name))


print("</html>")
```

If I remove the import mysql then form works fine again.  Is there something I'm missing?  This is running on Apache / MySQL server that I built.

EDIT
Here is Apache error log:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
[Thu Dec 08 12:08:32.460712 2022] [cgid:error] [pid 4890:tid 139695757391616] [client 172.16.19.73:60330] End of script output before headers: getData.py, referer: http://10.143.110.70/user_add.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/getData.py", line 3, in <module>
    import mysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
[Thu Dec 08 12:13:57.193858 2022] [cgid:error] [pid 4890:tid 139695790962432] [client 172.16.19.73:60658] End of script output before headers: getData.py, referer: http://10.143.110.70/user_add.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/getData.py", line 5, in <module>
    import mysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
[Thu Dec 08 12:29:46.442151 2022] [cgid:error] [pid 4890:tid 139695832925952] [client 172.16.19.73:61568] End of script output before headers: getData.py, referer: http://10.143.110.70/user_add.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/getData.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
[Thu Dec 08 12:32:06.582967 2022] [cgid:error] [pid 4890:tid 139695841318656] [client 172.16.19.73:61611] End of script output before headers: getData.py, referer: http://10.143.110.70/user_add.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/getData.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
[Thu Dec 08 12:56:43.385720 2022] [cgid:error] [pid 4890:tid 139695698642688] [client 172.16.19.73:62714] End of script output before headers: getData.py, referer: http://10.143.110.70/user_add.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/getData.py", line 5, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
[Thu Dec 08 13:37:12.045851 2022] [cgid:error] [pid 4662:tid 139695698642688] [client 172.16.19.73:64108] End of script output before headers: getData.py, referer: http://10.143.110.70/user_add.html
```

Comment: The Apache error logs should contain the error traceback - please [edit] the question to include it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I've added the apache logs.

Answer (score 0):

Well managed to find it after looking at the Apache error.  Had to install mysql connector:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).